# Can't connect to remote MySQL server on AWS, but ssh tunnel works

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up mysql so that a user 'imbnpandmkexby' can connect to database 'de0rllo43ct314' from any remote IP address, or locally.

=========== THESE ARE THE STEPS I'VE TAKEN: ===========

1) In my MySQL config, I have commented out the bind-address line, verified that skip-networking is not in the file, and restarted mysql:

```
#/etc/mysql/my.cnf:
#bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

2) I added remote permissions (by using the '%') for user 'imbnpandmkexby' on the desired database 'de0rllo43ct314':

```
[ remote ] > mysql -u root -p
[ mysql  ] > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON de0rllo43ct314.* TO 'imbnpandmkexby'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordhere' WITH GRANT OPTION;
[ mysql  ] > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON de0rllo43ct314.* TO 'imbnpandmkexby'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordhere' WITH GRANT OPTION;
[ mysql  ] > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON de0rllo43ct314.* TO 'imbnpandmkexby'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwordhere' WITH GRANT OPTION;
[ mysql  ] > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
[ mysql  ] > select * from mysql.user\G
```

This outputs:

```
*************************** 6. row ***************************
                  Host: localhost
                  User: imbnpandmkexby
              Password: *0000000000000000000000
...
*************************** 7. row ***************************
                  Host: 127.0.0.1
                  User: imbnpandmkexby
              Password: 
...
*************************** 8. row ***************************
                  Host: %
                  User: imbnpandmkexby
              Password: 
...
```

3) At this point I can connect with an SSH tunnel using Sequel Pro. The user appears to have all the right permissions.

[image]

4) Next I opened a firewall port and verified that MySQL is listening on that port:

```
[ remote ] > sudo iptables -I INPUT 10 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
[ remote ] > sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp     dpt:4505
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp     dpt:4506
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:zabbix-agent
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:zabbix-trapper
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Since this box is hosted on amazon ec2, I also opened up port 3306 in its security group:

[image]

5) I can telnet into the port:

```
Trying 00.00.00.000...
Connected to ec2-00.00.00.000.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

=========== THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK: ===========

00.00.00.000 shown instead of actual IP

When I try connecting to the database from my local machine, it doesn't work:

```
[ local ] > mysql -u imbnpandmkexby -h 00.00.00.000 -p
[ local ] > Enter password: 
[ local ] > ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '00.00.00.000' (61)
```

I am able to connect to a database on a dreamhost server, so it doesn't seem to be a block on my side:

```
[ local ] > mysql -u dreamhost_user -h mysql.dreamhostdomain.com -p
[ local ] > Enter password: 
[ local ] > Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```

Is there a layer of permissions that I'm missing?

Comment: It's not a grant issue, instead its a firewall involved in ec2 or at your location. If you are at an office, some companies restrict outbound to certain ports.

Comment: @datasage, I updated my description to show that I can connect to other mysql databases from my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out! I had a combination of two problems:

1) My SQL rule was coming after a REJECT rule in the iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:4505
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:4506
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:zabbix-agent
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:zabbix-trapper
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix "iptables denied: "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
```

What I did was remove the last rule, and re-add it at index 10:

```
[ remote ] > iptables -vnL --line-numbers ##Prints rules along with line numbers
[ remote ] > iptables -D INPUT 14
[ remote ] > sudo iptables -I INPUT 10 -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

I knew this was a step in the right direction because I was now able to connect to the box via telnet ("telnet 00.00.00.000 3306")

2) The second problem I has was that my MySQL user only had a password set on the 'localhost' user, not the users with access to '127.0.0.1' or '%'. It turns out that each user-host combination needs a password. Now when I run "select * from mysql.user\G" in the MySQL console, I get:

```
*************************** 6. row ***************************
                  Host: localhost
                  User: imbnpandmkexby
              Password: *0000000000000000000000
...
*************************** 7. row ***************************
                  Host: 127.0.0.1
                  User: imbnpandmkexby
              Password: *0000000000000000000000
...
*************************** 8. row ***************************
                  Host: %
                  User: imbnpandmkexby
              Password: *0000000000000000000000
...
```

Answer (score 0):

run tcpdump on mysql server to ensure tcp/3306 is actually getting to that box, or to see where its being blocked.

if connecting to remote tcp/3306 hangs and timeouts, its being blackholed or denied by a firewall.  if it comes back right away with cant connect, its most likely making it all the way to server, but being rejected (and tcp response is returned).

Comment: Hi @nandoP, I'm not familiar with tcpdump, so I googled for an example command. Is this what you'd suggest, or is there a better way to use tcpdump? Command `>>> "tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306" which returned >>> **"listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes"**`

Comment: thats the idea. if the server is seeing traffic, the packets would start flooding your console.  try running "tcpdump -i eth0" and see what i mean (hit ctrl-c to stop).  this test shows the tcp/3306 traffic is not getting to your aws instance.  do the same test at your office perimeter device (firewall), and see if the traffic is going thru the ipsec tunnel up to amazon.  is your connecting machine's network in ipsec phase2 config?